# How to concat & minify an angular2 application?

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, angular

I would like to concat & minify an angular2 application. What I did was first concatenating all my *.js files (boot.js, application.js then all components) in one file and injected it to my index.html. I also deleted the

```
<script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

and replaced it with my

```
<script src="js/allMyConcatFilesIntoOne.js"></script>
```

But I got the error, that require is missing/unknown.

How are angular2 applications filled into one file? Do I have to gather all typescript files first and then concat and then compile it via gulp?

Regards

Tenoda

Comment: Use webpack instead. Gulp is slower and more annoying to use. Webpack on the other hand is more complicated to configure. But when you do, it will do everything for you. Also it has nice [docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/). [Here is awsome starter repository](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter)

Answer (score 0):

Use a gulpfile.js like this:

```
/// <binding Clean='clean' />
            "use strict";

            var gulp = require("gulp"),
                rimraf = require("rimraf"),
                concat = require("gulp-concat"),
                cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
                uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
                tsc = require("gulp-typescript");

            var webroot = "./wwwroot/";

            var paths = {
                js: webroot + "js/**/*.js",
                ts: webroot + "app/**/*.ts",
                minJs: webroot + "js/**/*.min.js",
                css: webroot + "css/**/*.css",
                minCss: webroot + "css/**/*.min.css",
                concatJsDest: webroot + "js/site.min.js",
                concatCssDest: webroot + "css/site.min.css"
            };

            gulp.task("clean:js", function (cb) {
                rimraf(paths.concatJsDest, cb);
            });

            gulp.task("clean:css", function (cb) {
                rimraf(paths.concatCssDest, cb);
            });

            gulp.task("clean", ["clean:js", "clean:css"]);

            gulp.task("min:js", function () {
                return gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
                    .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
                    .pipe(uglify())
                    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
            });

            gulp.task("min:css", function () {
                return gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
                    .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
                    .pipe(cssmin())
                    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
            });

            gulp.task("min", ["min:js", "min:css"]);
```